# mod_wsgi psycopg2 importerror datetime initialization error

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, psycopg2

Everything runs perfectly if I use `manage.py` runserver but the moment I deploy using **apache+mod_wsgi** i get

```
ImportError: datetime initialization failed.
```

Environment details

```
    CentOS 6
    Apache/2.4.6 
    Python 3.5.1 on virtualenv
    postgresql-libs-8.4.20-4.el6_7.x86_64
```

Python Modules

```
Django==1.9.1
mod-wsgi==4.4.22
mod-wsgi-httpd==2.4.12.6
psycopg2==2.6.1
wheel==0.26.0
```

Error Log

```
[wsgi:warn] [pid 7826] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1.
[wsgi:warn] [pid 7826] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.0.
```

Virtual Host Log

```
    Loading WSGI script '/home/mkt/src/market/wsgi.py'.
    [wsgi:error] [pid 7828] mod_wsgi (pid=7828): Target WSGI script '/home/mkt/src/market/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    [wsgi:error] [pid 7828] mod_wsgi (pid=7828): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/mkt/src/market/wsgi.py'.
    [wsgi:error] [pid 7828] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [wsgi:error] [pid 7828]   File "/home/mkt/mktve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 20, in 
    [wsgi:error] [pid 7828]     import psycopg2 as Database
    [wsgi:error] [pid 7828]   File "/home/mkt/mktve/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in 
    [wsgi:error] [pid 7828]     from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
    [wsgi:error] [pid 7828] ImportError: datetime initialization failed
    [wsgi:error] [pid 7828]
```

Apache Config

    `Alias /static /home/mkt/src/market/static
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/mkt/src/market/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com python-path=/home/mkt/src:/home/mkt/mktve/lib/python3.5/site-packages user=myuser group=myuser
    WSGIProcessGroup  mysite.com`

```
<Directory /home/mkt/src/market/static>
    Require all granted
    #Allow from All
</Directory>
<Directory /home/mkt/src/market>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        #Satisfy Any
        #Allow from All
    </Files>
</Directory>
LogLevel info
```

LDD

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc7bd42000)
libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 (0x00007f2e42451000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2e42234000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2e4202f000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f2e41e2c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f2e41c24000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2e4199f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2e4160b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2e42b83000)
```

Note: I'm guessing that the problem is with **psycopg2+mod_wsgi** because another virtualhost on the same server running **sqlite** is working fine.

Comment: Is it only `mod-wsgi` that gives you this error? Can you run migrations and access the python shell with `manage.py shell`?

Comment: The exception is raised in `psycopg2/__init__.py`. It could be some internal bug with psycopg2. You could try submitting an issue on github. https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2

Comment: You may want to try running your app with gunicorn to test your wsgi with another server before filling a bug: http://gunicorn.org/

Comment: Yes, I can run migration. Everything is fine if I use manage.py. I'll check on gunicorn.org.

Comment: by the way before posting the question here, I saw a somewhat similar bug in psycopg2 but was flagged as problem of mod_wsgi.

Comment: I ran `python manage.py runmodwgi 0.0.0.0:8000` and it resulted to the same error. of course, `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` works perfectly fine.

Comment: @n3storm, it works with gunicorn. thanks for recommending that. I put it behind apache, though. probably for the time being, this will be my setup until mod_wsgi is updated.

Comment: @kwatog you are welcome. Just to let you know having the http server and application server so tight as in apache wsgi or apache php is not the best way to handle deployment, load balance, application evolution, ... I think you are in the right path now and I bet you will keep using gunicorn and maybe move to nginx if you have many users ;) Cheers